# How to apply value to all input from option change with jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to change the value of all `input:text` from the `select` menu. This value will change only the matched `td.class` from `data-pset` inside `<select>`

I can only think of this code. Please help me out where am I missing. (I'm new to jquery and still learning.)

```js
$("select.set_price").change(function() {
  var pset = $(this).data('pset');
  $(this).find('td.' + pset).find('input.price').val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th align="left">
      <select class="set_price" data-pset="set1">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Set1</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
      </select>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td class="set1"><input type="number" name="set1_1" value="1" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td class="set1"><input type="number" name="set1_2" value="1" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td class="set1"><input type="number" name="set1_3" value="1" /></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th align="left">
      <select class="set_price" data-pset="set1">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Set2</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
      </select>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td class="set2"><input type="number" name="set2_1" value="1" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td class="set2"><input type="number" name="set2_2" value="1" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td class="set2"><input type="number" name="set2_3" value="1" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I expect all inputs under each set to change the value accordingly to the select change. Please click here for the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/stgcd5k7/

Comment: you use `input.price` but none of your inputs have that class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's three issues in your jQuery code.

1. You're looking for the `td` elements *inside* the `select` as you call `find()`. Look for them from the DOM root instead.
2. You haven't added the `price` class to the `input` HTML.
3. The second `.set_price` element has its `data-pset` set to a value of `set1` instead of `set2`.

Fix those issues and the logic works correctly:

```js
$("select.set_price").change(function() {
  var pset = $(this).data('pset');
  $('td.' + pset).find('input.price').val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th align="left">
      <select class="set_price" data-pset="set1">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Set1</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
      </select>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td class="set1"><input type="number" name="set1_1" value="1" class="price" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td class="set1"><input type="number" name="set1_2" value="1" class="price"  /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td class="set1"><input type="number" name="set1_3" value="1" class="price"  /></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th align="left">
      <select class="set_price" data-pset="set2">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Set2</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
      </select>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td class="set2"><input type="number" name="set2_1" value="1" class="price"  /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td class="set2"><input type="number" name="set2_2" value="1" class="price"  /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td class="set2"><input type="number" name="set2_3" value="1" class="price"  /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I keep thinking that I always need `$(this)` to refer to `select` before finding input. This is confuse me every time sending data to element via jquery. Thank you very much for your working answer.

Comment: No problem, glad to help